# How to cast for bitwise shift

Tags: c, casting, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

I am trying to combine bits read in different 16-bit register into a single 32-bit variable with bit shifting (this is to get an ID stored split in different register in an interesting way on a sensor).

But there should have something about casting and bit shifting I am missing. Especially I cannot comprehend why in the example below `sum` and `id0_d + id1_d` lead to different results. I would prefer a solution like the way `sum` is computed without having to declare intermediate variables.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void) {
    uint16_t id0 = 0x4E00;
    uint16_t id1 = 0xABCD;
    uint32_t sum = ((uint32_t)id0)>>7 + ((uint32_t)id1)<<9;
    uint32_t id0_d = ((uint32_t)id0)>>7;
    uint32_t id1_d = ((uint32_t)id1)<<9;
    
    printf("id0: %04X\n", id0);
    printf("id1: %04X\n", id1);
    printf("sum: %08lx\n", sum);
    printf("id0_d: %08lx\n", id0_d);
    printf("id1_d: %08lx\n", id1_d);
    printf("id0+1_d: %08lx\n", id0_d + id1_d);
    return 0;
}
```

Which outputs the following:

```
id0: 4E00
id1: ABCD
sum: 00000000
     ^no the expected result
id0_d: 0000009c
id1_d: 01579a00
id0+1_d: 01579a9c
         ^expected result for "sum"
```

Comment: Operator precedence of addition versus shifting.  Use parentheses!  And avoid mixing arithmetic with bitwise operators.

Comment: It makes more sense logically to use `|` instead of `+`.

Comment: Puck, curious, why did code use `l` with `"%08lx"` and not `"%08x"` nor `"%" PRIx32`?

Comment: Actually, `|` has lower precedence than `<<` and `>>`, so if you replace `+` by the more idiomatic `|`, you also won't need the parentheses.  Though of course they don't hurt.

Comment: What's the shifts with 7 and 9 for? You should only need to shift one of the 16 bitters up 16 bit positions, then bitwise OR from there. Which is the same as +.

Comment: That is `uint32_t sum = ((uint32_t)id_1 << 16) | id_1;`. And that's it... am I missing something?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica it is a badly converted example, it was actually a uint64_t and the code is intended for a 32-bit microcontroller. But thanks for mentionning it, it might be useful to have explicit number of bits for prints

Comment: @Lundin yes, as mentioned, my example comes from a real life serial of a chip where the placement is weird, it is split in 3 registers and there is 7 leading bits not part of the serial.

Comment: Then mask with bitwise AND before shifting. Using shifts to "shift out" undesired bits is a common source of subtle bugs.

Answer (score 1):

Edit the following:

```
uint32_t sum = ((uint32_t)id0)>>7 + ((uint32_t)id1)<<9;
uint32_t id0_d = ((uint32_t)id0)>>7;
uint32_t id1_d = ((uint32_t)id1)<<9;
```

to: ensure that the operations are performed in the right order:

```
uint32_t sum = ((uint32_t)id0>>7) | ((uint32_t)id1<<9);
uint32_t id0_d = (uint32_t)id0>>7;
uint32_t id1_d = (uint32_t)id1<<9;
```

Using the arithmetic operator `+` in this example will produce the expected results, but with bitwise operations, the bitwise `|` is more commonly used

```
printf("id0+1_d: %08lx\n", id0_d + id1_d);
```

to

```
printf("id0+1_d: %08lx\n", id0_d | id1_d);
```

This will result in the expected output:

[image]